# How to add a background-gradient to a Toolbar

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to know how to create custom background gradient for a toolbar in sencha touch 2.

At the moment I'm using this code, I would like change Glossy with my custom gradient.

```
 @include sencha-toolbar-ui('custom-toolbar-1L', #555555,'glossy');
```

Please provide me with a sample of code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixin you are using generates the following CSS class:

```
.x-toolbar-custom-toolbar-1L {
    [..some glossy styles...]
}
```

If you know that you can simply create this CSS code by yourself or even better you can override the background gradient for this class after the mixin was called.

```
@include sencha-toolbar-ui('custom-toolbar-1L', #555555,'glossy');

.x-toolbar-custom-toolbar-1L {
    [..more awesome styles...]
}
```